# jQuery $.each on JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, parsing

Despite reading almost every article on the first page of Google about this, I can't seem to get this to work:

```
[ { "comment" : "Resources to learn the basics of financial markets and economic concepts",
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "Basics of Finance"
  },
  { "comment" : "Pictures of colourful artwork to uplift the mood.",
    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "Colourful Artwork"
  }
]
```

This is my JSON file which I want to parse with jQuery/javascript and use. This is what I'm trying at the moment:

```
$.ajax({ 
      url: 'yourcurations.php', 
      data: '', 
      dataType: 'json', 
      success: function(data){
        $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(i, item) {
        alert(item.name);
        });​
      }
    });
```

where 'data' is the JSON pasted above, but it's not working. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us how you got the "json" to be in the `data` variable. Is it actually an array literal, did you use ajax to get it, did you forget to parse it?

Comment: Blind guess: `$.each(JSON.parse(data), ...`

Comment: Updated the question with the full code, and tried parseJSON but still no luck

Comment: OK, thank you. If you're using [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with `dataType:'json'`, the ajax code automatically does the `$.parseJSON` for you - it should have worked as it was. So now we have to ask deeper: What exactly "does not work"? Does it not alert, does it not alert what is expected, does it throw an exception (check your error console) when attempting to loop, did the JSON file load correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned JSON data is already parsed because you already stated that it's JSON. And even without stating the return type, jQuery "guesses" the type of the data that's returned and parses it accordingly. Therefore, `data` is already an array and you don't need too parse anymore.

Also, use `console.log` when debugging. It gives you more detail about the value.

```
success: function(data){
  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    console.log(item.name);
  });​
}
```

Comment: @Taimur on modern browsers, it should be F12 or CTRL+SHIFT+I

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: @Bergi [a semicolon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006009/jquery-each-on-json/16006037?noredirect=1#comment22826411_16006037)?